# Regex match any li of ul that contains text

Tags: html, regex

I have a string

```
<ul><li>Option to add embroidered text personalization below design<br/>for only $1.00 per shirt and free setup</li><li>Men&#39;s Sizes: XS-6XL</li><li>Individually folded and bagged with size sticker for easy distribution</li><li>Ready to ship in 7 business days after art approval</li></ul>
```

Trying to match

```
<li>Men&#39;s Sizes: XS-6XL</li>
```

I am looking to take only the last `<li></li>` set that contains words

So for li that contains sizes I am looking to run something like:

```
(<li>).*?\b[sS]izes[ :]{1}.*?<\/li>
```

but that selects the first `<li>` instance instead of the closest.

EDIT: I can't use a html parser here like HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: Hang on.. I've got a great link somewhere round here that talks in some depth about using Regex to parse HTML...

Comment: Ok but I am not looking for a htmlparser like HTMLAgilityPack here

Comment: ..[found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) .. By the way, have you thought about setting [RTL search direction on your Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options), if you have a pattern that matches the first but you want the last?

Comment: You say "*I am looking to take only the last `<li></li>` set that contains words*" and also that you're "*[trying] to match `<li>Men&#39;s Sizes: XS-6XL</li>`.*" Did you mean you want to match the last `li` element that contains the words `Men&#39;s sizes`?

Comment: Eh. This tells me to forget about it and use htmlagilitypack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the pattern:

```
<li>[^<]*[Ss]izes[^<]*<\/li>
```

Which works like:

| Element | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| `<li>` | The opening tag |
| `[^<]*` | Zero or more characters that are not the start of a new tag (`<`) |
| `[Ss]izes` | The keyword we are looking for |
| `[^<]*` | Zero or more characters that are not the start of a new tag (`<`) |
| `<\/li>` | The closing tag |

[Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/rLd2Sa/1/)

And I'd take the last such matching element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML and innetText properties like this:

```js
const str = "<ul><li>Option to add embroidered text personalization below design<br/>for only $1.00 per shirt and free setup</li><li>Men&#39;s Sizes: XS-6XL</li><li>Individually folded and bagged with size sticker for easy distribution</li><li>Ready to ship in 7 business days after art approval</li></ul>"
const el1 = document.createElement('div')
el1.innerHTML = str;
let liArr = el1.getElementsByTagName('li')
let resultsText = [] 
let resultsHTML = []
for (const listElement of liArr) {
    if(listElement.innerText.indexOf('Size') >-1){
        resultsText.push(listElement.innerText)
        resultsHTML.push(listElement)
    }
}
console.log('resultsText:::::::::::::')
console.log(resultsText)
console.log('resultsHTML::::::::::::')
console.log(resultsHTML)
```